# How can I get a cstring into a class?

Tags: c++

I'm going to using cstring finish the program
now I required to get the name of PokemonWorld from user
and initialize it

But I can't get the cstring from main() into class PokemonWorld

I tried `cin >> world.setName` and `cin >> name; world.setName(name)`

both of which failed

```
class PokemonWorld {
private:
char name[10];
public:
void setName(char x[]) {
    *name = x;
};
char* getName(){
    return name;
};
};

void main() {
PokemonWorld world;
int number;
char name[10];
cout << "What is the World Name ?" ;
cin >> name;

world.setName(name);
```

Also I cannot using getName to return the name that assigned into PokemonWorld

Here is the error code:

Error   C3867   'PokemonWorld::getName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Should I create PokemonWorld as pointer?

Comment: The issue you're encountering doesn't have anything to do with getting a cstring inside the class. Your question should be, how to properly implement a setter and getter for a cstring.

Comment: ohh sorry because I delete some part that no related to this problem
But now there are error that in the function setName(char x[])
It said that a value type "char *" cannot be assigned to an enity of type "char"

Comment: The issue in your code is that your setter doesn't work, and there are issues with your getter as well. The answers given will hint at solutions, but I think it's better to ask the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `cstring`, you have to use c string manipulator. You definitively can't assign an array to another one. For your issue, use [`strncpy_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
void setName(char x[]) {
    strncpy_s(name, 10, x, 10);
};
```

Also, to avoid issue, your getter should be:

```
const char * const getName() const {
    return name;
};
```

Also, to compare, use `strncmp`, to concatenate use `strncat`, ...

Or, because you use c++, use `std::string`

Comment: the requirement of this work is only can use cstring...
I tried the method of using strncpy,but the VS ask me to use strncpy_s

Moreover, set the char* getName as const still have some proble

Comment: Error C3867 'PokemonWorld::getName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Here is the error code

Comment: @丹生谷森夏 So use strncpy_s instead of strncpy... The main point of this answer is: you can't assign array with operator `=`, you have to use function.

Comment: @丹生谷森夏 And for error C3897, I think issue comes from another part of your code, can you give code which produce this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name first. In your main method,

```
PokemonWorld world;
int number;
char name[10];
cout << "What is the World Name ?" ;
cin >> name;
world.setName(name);
//Then get the name
    world.getName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a cstring (most people who hear "cstring" think of the `CString` class of the MFC library).

You are using a "C" string, or a raw char pointer. This is bad practice in general, as it involves performing memory management manually, and unless you solve the problems that come with using raw pointers, you will simply have those problems in your code.

setName should be:

```
void setName(char const * const x)
{
    auto length = std::min(std::strlen(x), 9); // only copy up to 9 characters
    std::copy_n(x, length, name);
    name[length] = '\0';
}
```

... or (as already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759153/186997)):

```
strncpy_s(name, 10, x, 10);
```

getName should be:

```
char const * const getName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

This code is almost correct:

```
char name[10];
cout << "What is the World Name ?" ;
cin >> name;
world.setName(name);
```

... but you should initialize name where you declare it:

```
char name[10] = { 0 };
```

Also, what will you do if the user inputs more than 10 characters? In that case the stack of your program will become corrupted.

You could avoid the problem by using a std::string.